# etiqueta iframe (marcos)

Tags: php, css

Estoy trabajando con esta etiqueta,
Dentro del 'iframe' incluyo la imagen de una pagina web dentro de  marco.

```
<iframe src="<?=$sitio_web['url']?>" width="540" height="250"></iframe>
```

Ahora bien... el problema que tengo es que hay sitios webs que no se visualizan correctamente y claro no aparecen dentro del marco, estos sitios webs se pasan de las medidas que tengo establecidas.

Me gustaria saber si puedo establecer algun tipo de parametro en CSS o PHP que validase si dicha web 'rompe' el marco o dicho de otro modo no se 'incrustase' correctamente dentro.

Gracias

Comment: La etiqueta tiene varios atributos para controlar su funcionamiento que tal vez te eviten el uso de CSS o PHP. Sin embargo, no queda muy claro tu problema. ¿Cómo llegaste a la conclusión de que "se pasan de las medidas"?.¿Podés poner ejemplos de sitios que si funcionen y otros que no?.

Comment: Si perdona si no me he explicado bien. Un ejemplo hay sitios webs que llevan incorporados pop-ups y entonces rompen dicho marco de visualizacion. Lo ideal seria si el 'iframe' tiene dentro contenido o no, y poder controlar esto.

Comment: Hmmm. Suponiendo que pudieras determinar si hubo un problema, ¿qué debería hacerse?

Answer (score 0):

La opción más sencilla para de alguna manera controlar el contenido de un *IFRAME*, es utilizar el atributo "***sandbox***" . Éste habilita una serie de restricciones al contenido de la etiqueta *IFRAME*, de manera tal que bloquea la ejecución de scripts, el envío (submit) de formularios, las ventanas modales o popups, etc.

Si quisieras aplicar el máximo de restricciones usando este atributo en tu código de ejemplo, sería:

```
<iframe sandbox src="<?=$sitio_web['url']?>" width="540" height="250"></iframe>
```

Si esto fuera demasiado restrictivo, podés relajar algunas restricciones pasando una lista de valores al atributo.
Por ejemplo, si querés permitir formularios sería:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms" src="<?=$sitio_web['url']?>" width="540"height="250"></iframe>
```

Fuente :[w3schools (en inglés)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp)

Por otro lado, si necesitás tener un mayor control sobre el contenido del IFRAME podrías usar javascript para interactuar con los elementos del documento incrustado a través de esta etiqueta.

[Por ejemplo,](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp) si quisieras ocultar el primer elemento `<H1>` dentro de un IFRAME:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
elmnt.style.display = "none";
```

Para más información sobre IFRAMEs y javascript, incluyendo algunos ejemplos, podés visitar esta [página](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/) (en inglés).

Saludos!

Comment: bien... pero como puedo controlar mediante una variable si el atributo 'sandbox' recibe uan restriccion del contenido o no, mediante un condicional  'if'

Comment: La idea de "sandbox" es una manera sencilla de bloquear/permitir deteminados tipos de contenido. Algo más complejo requiere algún control con javascript sobre el documento del IFRAME.

Comment: donde puedo encontrar algun ejemplo con javascript ? y que de como resultado frame 'correcto' o 'incorrecto'